# Significance of the door Levee is trying to unlock

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, ma-raineys-black-bottom

In the movie *Ma Rainey’s Black Bottom*, Levee character is shown to be always trying to break free from his own self and do something beyond his steady band performer role. He keeps talking about a door in the rehearsal room, which the other band members say wasn’t there before and now being there.

Was this an allusion that Levee being hopeful of a way out of his current monotonous life and break free, but then towards the end realizes it’s only a closed wall with no hope?